# how to show a div tag when i click on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My program is to upload a file and when I click on *Upload* it will call a servlet. the same upload page contain some other fields which should b displayed when I click on upload button only. how to call the servlet as well as to show the remaining contents. Actually using the servlet I want to show the file contents on same page.

here is my code.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="regist" action="Registration"
            onsubmit="return validateFile((this))" enctype="multipart/form-data"
            method="post">

            <div class="control-group" class="span12">
                <label class="control-label" for="file">Please upload a
                    file:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="file" name="file"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<div id="showFrames" style="display:none;">

<!--
  hidden contents are here -->

</div>
```

and my script is

```
function validateFile(form) {
        var fileName = form.file.value;
        if (!fileName) {
            alert("No File Selected!!!");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#showFrames").show();
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work. can anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery I'll do it like that :

```
$('.form-horizontal').sumbit(function(e) {
    if($(this).find('input[type="file"]').val().length) { //check by length
        $("#showFrames").show();
    } else {
        alert('No file Selected');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It'll be better using a form ID if you need to have more than one form.

This way you can remove the `onsubmit` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace your as per below
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="regist" action="Registration"
        onsubmit="return validateFile(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        method="post">

        <div class="control-group" class="span12">
            <label class="control-label" for="file">Please upload a
                file:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="file" name="file"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```